# Get a data from a web page into a PDF format using Tomahawk in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, sandbox, tomahawk

i am a newbie to `JSf` and Tomahawk Technology. In application i am having a datatable, i want store the information from he data table into a PDF format on a click of a button using `Tomahawk` and `SandBox`.Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, use [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports). It uses iText behind the scene to export reports to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You may need [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) for this.
Also see this - http://www.junlu.com/msg/281869.html

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you are using sandbox, use `exporterActionListener` component in the sandbox to export the data from data tabel into PDF. You need the itext-0.99.jar use the same version

**Code sample**

```
<!-- sandbox tag library declaration -->
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/sandbox" prefix="s"%>
   .
   .  <!-- your data Tabel will be here -->
   .
   .

<h:commandButton value="Export as pdf">
     <s:exporterActionListener for="Id of the Data Tabel" fileType="PDF" />
</h:commandButton>
```